# How can I shut off the confirmation prompt when I delete conversations in Messages in OS X?

Tags: messages

I receive a lot of messages on my MacBook Pro on a daily basis. Periodically throughout the day I need to delete multiple conversations in messages for clarity purposes. Each time I delete a conversation thread I receive the following prompt:

[image: Delete Confirmation Pop Up Dialog Box]

I have looked around in Messages preferences and I can not see any readily apparent option to disable the deletion confirmation pop-up dialog box. Is there any way to disable this dialog in Messsages or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the preferences as well as `defaults`, there does not appear to be a way to disable the confirmation message.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a workaround. If you enable the "Save history when conversations are closed" option under Preferences->Messages, you won't be prompted when deleting conversations.

Comment: Yes I saw this some time ago but I currently do not wish to enable this functionality. It is however, a semi-viable work around.

Answer (score 3):

You can hold Option and click Delete or (x).

Comment: This seems to be new behavior since I originally posted this question.

Comment: And now in MacOS 12.1 (Montery) it doesn't work again. So disappointing when the OS makes backward steps.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out..... Strangely you have to click on save messages history when closed then you can just delete and it does away without asking for confirmation. Seems like it would be the opposite... I hope this helps.